# Python derive new Dictionary from search in lists

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, combinations

I have 2 list: A is for tag names, B is for values, they're related by the same index position.
I need to perform a search to extract only some value from the lists. This is the best way to do it?

Steps:

1) get the list of tag names that I need from external source

```
tobesearched = [pippo, pluto]
```

2) search the tag names in a list of availables tags and store index position.

```
globalTagnames = [gigi, pippo, giongion, pluto, giagia]
 indexposition=    0      1       2       3       4
```

3) search the values in another list, with as reference the index of the tag name in previous list.

```
values= [10,11,12,13,14]
```

3) put the tag names with values from another list in a dictionary:

```
mydict = {pippo:11, pluto:13}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need indexposition array. you can do as below

```
    for index,tag in enumerate(globalTagnames):
      if tag in tobesearched:
         print values[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict:

```
>>> globalTagnames = ['gigi', 'pippo', 'giongion', 'pluto', 'giagia']
>>> values = range(10, 15)
```

Create a dict from `globalTagnames`, `values` using `zip` and `dict()`:

```
>>> dic = dict(zip(globalTagnames, values))
>>> dic
{'giongion': 12, 'pippo': 11, 'gigi': 10, 'giagia': 14, 'pluto': 13}
```

Now iterate over items to be searched using a dict-comprehension to create a new dict.
Now the index of any item can be found in `O(1)` time:

```
>>> tobesearched = ['pippo', 'pluto'] 
>>> {item:dic[item] for item in tobesearched}
{'pippo': 11, 'pluto': 13}
```